# STUN/TURN servers in WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

I started learning webRTC  a few days back. WebRTC follows offer/answer model. Do all the exchanges(metadata, network information, and media streams) follow this model? Do we need of STUN/TURN servers in all the exchanges. After getting the public IPs of the peers from STUN/TURN server for the first time, peer to peer communication can be started .

Comment: Is this question about other communication protocols or about webrtc? What do you mean by "all exchanges"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebRTC follow SIP and SDP protocol using a signaling server to do so.

All of this is used with the RTCPeerConnection. RTCPeerConnection is initiate with TURN/STUN servers. STUN/TURN is only usefull to generate ICE Candidate. You can use webrtc without Stun and Turn, it only means it will not be able to establish a peer-to-peer connection between every network (firewall and NAT are problematic mostly).

You don't need at all STUN/TURN for the offer/answer part. It only need a signaling server. STUN/TURN is usefull only in the ICE protocol that is a different flow than the Offer/Answer part. But of course, you need to do both to have a working peer-to-peer connection.

After Offer/Answer are exchange, both peer gather ICE candidate and send it to the other peer. Then ICE find the best way to establish the peer-to-peer and so the communication begin.

If you have moire question, go for it if ou don't find the answer elsewhere.

Comment: @Jujuelder If the caller is behind a symmetric NAT , then we need to use a TURN server for relaying. in this case do we need relaying for all the peer to peer connections?

Comment: If someone is behind symetric NAT, any peer-to-peer connection with this person will only be able using a TURN server as relaying

Comment: @Jujuelder While using Webrtc , do RTCpeerConnection  take care of the issues with STUN/TURN?

Comment: Only if you refer the TURN/STUN server whan you create the RTCPeerConnection. You can use public turn/stun server to start

Comment: @Jujuelder if I am using my own STUN and signalling server, then Is it possible to use all the WebRTC APIs?

Comment: I'am not sure what is the question. You can always use all WebRTC API.

Comment: @Jujuelder Is it possible to alert a user about the incoming call even if he isn't using a browser with WebRTC

Comment: I have no idea, ask a new question in stackoverflow, maybe someone know, i would up your question

Comment: "WebRTC follow SIP and SDP protocol using a signaling server to do so." => misleading. WebRTC is completely signaling agnostic. Signaling *can* be achieved by SIP, but it is only one possibility.

Comment: Can you give some other protocol possibility for signaling ?